# Ignore Specific Types of Changes with Github

Tags: github, github-for-windows, alteryx

I am relatively new to GitHub and I am primarily using it for Python development, but also a little of Alteryx for VC purposes.

Alteryx loves creating/changing temp files, so everytime I save the workflow, I get dozens of changes that aren't actually 'changes'.

Here is an example
[image]

Is there a way to remove/set a block on changes with the tag TempFile? It makes it difficult to locate the actual changes I have made

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want GitHub to ignore lines that match a specific pattern. I don't think GitHub provides any mechanism for that. However it does provide ways to ignore files. But looks like that's not what you are looking for.

Comment: @AsifKamranMalick Yea that's what I've been seeing so far in my search. But yes you are right about the intent for this.